# how to generate consecutive records with a given number?

Tags: sql, oracle

in oracle, is there a built-in function to produce consecutive records with a given number? For example, the number is `100`, so that you can generate a result-set with 100 records whose values are 1, 2, 3, 4...100, like the following:

**1

2

3

4

...

100**

I know store procedure can do this, and I want to know if there are other ways just using sql statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select level 
from dual 
connect by level <= 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, using `model` clause. (Oracle 10g and higher).

```
SQL> select x
  2    from dual
  3    model
  4    dimension by (0 as z)
  5    measures (0 as x)
  6    rules iterate(101) (
  7      x[iteration_number] =  iteration_number
  8    )
  9  ;

         X
----------
         0
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10
        11

        ...

        100
```

Comment: finally someone using the `model clause` +1

Answer (score 1):

Please try using CTE:

```
WITH numbers(n) AS
(
SELECT 1 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1 FROM numbers WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT * FROM numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's traditional to use a hierarchical query:

```
 select level
   from dual
connect by level <= 100
```